# Apache POI how to output as .xlsx

Tags: java, excel

I am writing a program that outputs an Excel workbook. I built it to output as a .xls file since the guide I used was older. Now I think I need the bigger size of the .xlsx.
What do I need to change in my code? I have tried just changing the file extension to .xlsx in the fileOutputStream and it gives me an error when I try to open the excel file.

Comment: Did you use `XSSFWorkbook` or `HSSFWorkbook`, the former should have no problems saving as `.xlsx` the latter is limited to `.xls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace everywhere HSSF for XSSF classes.
Instead of creating a `HSSFWorkbook` you need a `XSSFWordbook`. Instead of `HSSFRow` you need `XSSFRow` and so on.

The two formats (xls and xlsx) are not compatible at all which other.

Luckily the guys at POI did the code in a way that this transition will be fairly easy, depending on the complexity of your excel file.

Comment: That worked thanks! My problem was I didn't add the xml library so Eclipse didn't know what to do with XSSF thanks!